# Close linestring to linering in PostGis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, line

is there a function which closes a `linestring` to a `linering`? I couldn't found such a function in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean connecting the endpoint of a line to the startpoint? This should help http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AddPoint.html.